# Asynchronously Load an Image from a Url to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, webrequest

I want to load image from the web on windows forms application,
Everything is good and code works fine, but the problem is the app stop working until the loading goes to finish.
I want to see and work with app **without waiting to loading** .

```
PictureBox img = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
var request = WebRequest.Create(ThumbnailUrl);

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    img.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: Time to research `BackgroundWorker` and `asnyc`.

Comment: thank you , I search now

Comment: Do it in a backgroundworker `dowork` event rather

Comment: @Rahul , thank you, I going to search about backgroundworker dowork

Comment: BackgroundWorker has fallen out of favor with async/await. If you are going to spend your time learning, may as well learn todays tech.

Comment: I think this article can be useful: [Basics of Task](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

Comment: `PictireBox` control supports loading images asynchronously itself and you don't need to use background worker or async/await. It also loads image from a url, so you don't need to use a web request. You can simply use `LoadAsync` methd or `ImageLocation` property of `PictureBox`. The value of `WaitOnLoad` property should be false which is default. See the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Image>();
    Image webImage = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) task.Result;
            Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            else if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

            if (responseStream != null) webImage = Image.FromStream(responseStream);
            tcs.TrySetResult(webImage);
            webResponse.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
        });
    return tcs.Task.Result;
}
```

Here is how to call the above solution:

```
PictureBox img = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
var result = GetImageAsync(ThumbnailUrl);
result.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    img.Image = task.Result;
});
```

Comment: are you missing something like '**)**' , because the code doesn't work

Comment: So thank you, it was fantastic, dameeeet garm yaser jan

Comment: `PictireBox` control supports loading images asynchronously itself and you don't need to use background worker or async/await. You can simply use [`LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww2xzydc(v=vs.110).aspx) methd of `PictureBox`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sometimes you have to receive the picture from a site which it needs to add a header and some cookies. Consenquently, you will be allowed to get the picture.

Comment: @YasserBazrforoosh Yes. It would be useful for future readers if they have such requirement. The comment is just to inform readers of such built-in support in `PictureBox` for loading image asynchronously from a URL :)

Comment: @YasserBazrforoosh why use a TCS and `ContinueWith` when `async/awai` is already available? `var response= Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(..)` will return the response and get back to the UI thread. `ConfigureAwait(false)` can be used to avoid that, eg to allow loading the image in a threadpool thread.  There's no need for any of the `ContinueWith()` calls.

Comment: Also, checking if the stream is a GZip or Deflate stream is useless. Just set the [AutomaticDecompression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression) property of the `WebRequest` to `true` and it's all handled automatically.

Answer (score 8):

`PictureBox` control has built-in support for loading images asynchronously. You don't need to use BackgroundWorker or async/await. It also can load an image from a URL, so you don't need to use a web request.

You can simply use the [`LoadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method or [`ImageLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `PictureBox`. The value of [`WaitOnLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property should be `false`, which is the default.

```
pictureBox1.LoadAsync("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4tAc.jpg");
```

It's equivalent to:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4tAc.jpg";
```