# I wish to avoid form freezing during load large files to show

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I made my own FilePreviewHandler for preview some files like Explorer because currently I made custom file browser.

When I click items on ListView, I can preview files like explorer.

The PreviewHandler which is in my file browser Contains WebBrowser Class for load Movie/Text files,
PictureBox for load Image files, and ShellExPreviewHandler for other extensions.

The problem which engaged is like this.

When I attempt to load large file such 100mb or more large file or big image file like 8000x4000 pixels, form freezes until it load file.

**Code Area for PreviewHandler :**

```
    public void Open( String FileName )
    {
        if ( !Enabled || Last == FileName )
        {
            return;
        }
        //FileName = DriveUtil.RevealPath( FileName );

        String FileType = MIMEAssistant.GetMIMEType( FileName );
        // Image Files
        if ( ImagePreviewTarget.Where( x => FileType.Contains( x ) ).Count() > 0 )
        {
            IsProgress = true;
            try
            {
                if ( ImagePreviewHandler.Image != null )
                {
                    ImagePreviewHandler.Image.Dispose();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                Image TargetImage = Image.FromFile( FileName );
                if ( TargetImage.Width > this.Width || TargetImage.Height > this.Height )
                {
                    ImagePreviewHandler.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                }
                else
                {
                    ImagePreviewHandler.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                }
                ImagePreviewHandler.Image = TargetImage;
                ImagePreviewHandler.BringToFront();
            }
            catch
            {
                ImagePreviewHandler.Image = null;
                GC.Collect();
                ShellExPreviewHandler.BringToFront();
                IsProgress = false;
            }
        }


        // WebPreviewArea
        // This area doesn't make any problem. So I hide my codes on here.


        // PdfPreviewArea
        // Currently I don't use Pdf PreviewHandler. So I also hide my codes on here.

        // Other extensions
        else
        {
            ShellExPreviewHandler.Open( FileName );
            ShellExPreviewHandler.BringToFront();
        }

        Last = FileName;
    }
```

**What I Tried :**

I tried to use Thread, Task.Run, Backgroundworker for this, but all of this requires MyForm.Invoke to draw controls.

Thread Part =>

```
        Thread Preview = new Thread( (ThreadStart) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if ( FilePreview != null && Browser.PreviewOpened )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "FilePreview.Open Task Start" );
                    FilePreview.Open( Browser.SelectedPath );
                    Console.WriteLine( "FilePreview.Open Task Completed" );
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.StackTrace );
            }

            Process = false;
        } );

        Preview.Start();
        if ( Preview.Join( TimeSpan.Zero ) )
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 50 );
            while ( Process )
            {
                if ( dt + Interval < DateTime.Now )
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    dt = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
```

Task.Run Part =>

```
var t = Task.Run( () =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke( new MethodInvoker( delegate
                {
                    if ( Browser.SelectedItems.Count == 0 )
                    {
                        FilePreview.Initialize(); 
                        return;
                    }
                    else if ( Browser.SelectedItems[0].ForeColor == Color.Pink )
                    {
                        FilePreview.Initialize();
                        return;
                    }

                    if ( FilePreview != null && Browser.PreviewOpened )
                    {
                        FilePreview.Open( Browser.SelectedPath );
                    }
                } ) );
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        } );
```

BackgroundWorker =>

```
    private void PreviewWorker_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {
        FilePreviewHandler FilePreview = null;
        GCS.Windows.Forms.FileFolderList Browser = null;

        switch ( PreviewStatus ) {
            case BrowserStatus.Local:
                FilePreview = LocalFilePreviewHandler;
                Browser = LocalBrowser;
                break;
            case BrowserStatus.Network:
                FilePreview = NetFilePreviewHandler;
                Browser = NetworkBrowser;
                break;
        }

        if ( FilePreview == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Invoke( new MethodInvoker( delegate
        {
            FilePreview.Open( Browser.SelectedPath );
        } ) );
    }
```

I think this part makes my program freezing.

any idea to avoid form freezing during load large files for PreviewHandler?

Comment: [Asynchronously Load an Image from a Url to a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764953/3110834)

Comment: @bommelding sorry, carried away. There's probably a dozens identical questions per day, asking for a way to modify the UI from another thread. Typically, it's tables, not files

Comment: @arphile - you didn't show _how_ you were using Task.Run etc. To get this right you need to get the whole process right. `async` is preferred, starting with an async void event handler and awaiting all the way down to a Task.Run() or an Image.LoadAsync()

Comment: When you call Preview.Join()  right after Preview.Start() you are still single threaded.

Comment: A Task.Run()  that does _everything_ inside an Invoke() is also single threading.

Comment: A BackgroundWorker should also avoid Invoke() for the same reason. Invoke means 'execute on main thread' and that's what is freezing you.

Comment: The duplicat from Reza shows some good but incomplete solutions. The tricky part is how you call al this from the main thread, ie the event that starts it all.

Comment: If you ever code `GC.Collect()` or `Application.DoEvents()` then you are probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: @bommelding Thanks for tip!

Comment: Solved with comment tips!

Comment: what I did was add thread and do tasks without invoke with this property

Comment: CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

Comment: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` is very wrong. That's just like disabling the smoke detector. It won't stop the fire.

Comment: @bommelding that's okay for this purpose. what I need was prevent freezing. and it doesn't make other problems. if it's required, I think this way is right way to solve the problem.

Comment: No, you didn't solve anything. You now have a bug that is just very hard to reproduce.

Comment: @bommelding then how can I solve this problem without using invoke? any solutions?

Comment: See the first 1st and 3rd comments here. It's a standard problem that has been asked and answered many times. Separate your UI work from the heavy load stuff. For async, see Stephen Cleary's blog.